# Mat input value vs display text

Tags: angular-material

I have some mat-selects and autocompletes and they all take an object and display one value but when I post the form to the server it sends a different value. I am trying to accomplish the same with a normal mat input but I don't see a way to set the value and display text differently. I currently have an input like this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
<mat-label>Name</mat-label>
<input matInput type="text" formControlName="name">
</mat-form-field>
```

I would like the input to accept an object like this:

```
person= {
userName = 'testname1',
firstName = 'John',
lastName = 'Smith'
}
```

and in the text box display person.firstName + ' ' + person.lastName but the value of the input should be person.userName

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried to set the value and the displayed text differently but to no success.

The trick that worked for me is adding a new variable in the TypeScript file and an 'onSelectionChange()' event in the input. That way when the value from the dropdown is changed, the user sees it, but also the added event is called, in which I pass the desired value needed for the server to place in the new variable.

Last thing, before making the request from the server, I place the desired value in the place of the shown one so the server gets the right format it needs.

HTML file

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
   <mat-option
      *ngFor="let sample of samples$ | async"
      [value]="sample.name"
      (onSelectionChange)="setVariable(sample.id)"
   >
      {{ sample.name }}
   </mat-option>
```

TypeScript file

```
onSubmit() {
   this.sampleFormGroup.desiredValue = sample.id;
   // Server request
}
```